# Quip - The package has an invalid value for script_srcs: https://platform.quip.com

Tags: quip, liveapps

I want to access the Quip Automation API from my Live App.

But I cannot add `https://platform.quip.com` to `script_srcs`.

I get the following error when trying to upload the `app.ele`.

```
The package has an invalid value for script_srcs: https://platform.quip.com
```

Is this a restriction enforced by Quip Live Apps platform?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to add https://platform.quip.com to script_srcs, you should add it in Auth configuration of your app. Check out this example: https://github.com/quip/quip-apps/tree/master/examples/quip-automation-api-oauth2

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately to use oauth2 to authenticate with quip you need to be an enterprise customer which is too expensive for me. I need to support the personal access token approach.